# Menu Button for Android 5.0 / Lollipop

Tags: applications, share-menu

I recently upgraded from an Android 4.4/KitKat Samsung S4 to an Android 5.0/Lollipop Asus Zenfone 2. On my Android 4.4 device, there was a menu button on the bottom left. On my new Zenfone there is no menu button on the bottom of the phone or anywhere else on the device. ON the Zenfone, the return button is now on the bottom left and the Previous selections are on the bottom right.  There is a menu function on the Operating system of my phone to the upper right with 3 dots, but that is on the OS of the phone..  My question is where do I find the menu function to use within an app.  Many apps use a menu to do certain tasks. Please advise - thank you.

Comment: According Material design - Lollipop on wards, you have a button (3 dots you mentioned) called [Action Overflow Button](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#ActionButtons) which replaces the menu-button function.

Comment: Any legacy apps not targeting ICS or higher will get a compatibility mode menu button on the bottom right of the navigation bar. If you don't have a navigation bar but have physical keys, I suspect a custom launcher like Nova can allow you to remap one of your keys to showing a menu on a long press or double tap, or even as the default.

Comment: try long pressing your recent app button

Answer (score 3):

I just moved to the ZenFone2 from a moto razr as well. Not having a menu button is NOT going to happen. A bit of digging, and found the option to set the recent apps button to menu, on long press. :settings/device/asus customized settings/

Comment: Thor can you please be more explicit in your instructions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try back button, press and hold a few seconds. It works on my phone Samsung.